# Redirect with javascript "&" in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, redirect

I am trying to use JavaScript for redirecting to affiliate links.
The problem is that the url contains `&` which changes to `&amp;` after the redirect.

```
location.href ="http://affiliatelink.com/?a=xxxxx&e=xxxx"
```

will in the web browser be changed to

`http://affiliatelink.com/?a=xxxxx&amp;e=xxxx`

With `&amp;` in the url the affiliate link doesn't work.

How can I fix this problem? `encodeURIComponent()`?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant source code. Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to use Javascript for redirecting to affiliate links.
The problem is that the url contains "&" which adds amp; in the url after the redirect. 

location.href ="http://affiliatelink.com/a=xxxxx&e=xxxx"
will in the web browser be changed to http://affiliatelink.com/a=xxxxx&(amp;)e=xxxx (without the "()"). With amp; in the url the affiliate link doesn't work. 

How can I fix this problem? encodeURIComponent()?

Comment: There is no reason the browser would change the & to &amp; - it is more likely the server that does that. Try capturing the redirects. Also repeating the complete text of your question in an explaining comment does not add to our understanding.

Comment: Where is the link generated? It should just go to the url without changing the `&` to `&amp;`.

Comment: sorry I cant edit. Don't you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yeah maybe its the server but this makes the link not working.

Comment: I think something else is going on. Perhaps you are using some templating language like SMARTY that replaces the & with &amp; on the server before you serve the page

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to `%encode` the URL with the `encodeURIComponent` function...

```
encodeURIComponent('&') >> "%26"
```

Do this by popping the URL in the brackets of the `encodeURIComponent` function...

```
var myURL = 'http://address.web/?info=data&info=data';
var encodeURL = encodeURIComponent( myURL );
```

... or you could use the traditional string `.replace()` method...

```
var reg = new RegExp( '&', g );
var myURL = 'http://address.web/?info=data&info=data';
var encodeURL = myURL.replace( reg, '%26' );
```

The first method has the advantage of catching all `%encode`-able characters, where the second method only deals with `&`s.

Comment: Why and where would this be used? You do not even have & in your url examples

Answer (score 0):

This is because you transfer your url from code behind, perhaps you can try to deal with the url in the front-end like hardcode in javascript, then your problem will be solved.

In my case, I gather my url from xml(web.config) and xml should be used & , so I change the way for placing parameter(url) in the xml, in stead of placing the parameter(url) in the javascript.

For your reference! :)